# Visual Studio The Specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

Tags: vb.net, odbc, database-connection, connection-string, composite

**ERROR [IM014][Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager]The Specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application**

I am only getting this error in visual studio when i try to add a Data Connection.
When I test the connection in ODBC Data Source Administrator, it completes successfully.

I am trying to configure the TIBCO(R) Data Virtualization 7.0 Driver with Composite so that I could connect my web app in visual studio to the composite database.
Both the driver and composite studio are both 7.0 64 bit, along with my computer.

Answer (score 0):

I would say that your Visual Studio IDE is 32-bit.

As discussed in [this article on my employer's website](http://wikis.openlinksw.com/UdaWikiWeb/MsSqlOn64bitWin) which I believe [remains accurate](https://www.google.com/search?q=%2264-bit%20Visual%20Studio%22) --

> The Visual Studio IDE, up to and including VS2015 *[and later]*, [is a 32-bit application](http://www.quora.com/Why-is-Visual-Studio-2015-still-a-32-bit-application) and as a result, for such development all OLE DB and .NET Providers must be 32-bit, as must any subsequently interfaced components such as ODBC drivers.